# How can I prevent Quarkus with @RolesAllowed from randomly returning a 401 response?

Tags: http, jax-rs, quarkus, basic-authentication

I am making use of the @RolesAllowed annotation along with the Quarkus basic auth.
With high traffic, I get random 401 responses. The frequency of issues seems to depend on the environment (machine resources, with/without docker).
Some investigation showed that the security context is empty when the issue occurs.

I created a simple project to reproduce the issue here:
https://github.com/florian-signoret-ibm/quarkus-basic-auth-issue

It contains a test which sends parallel requests and detects unexpected error responses.

Thanks for your help!
Florian

Comment: Hi, I opened https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/33602 to track this bug, cheers